# JavaFx Scene Builder динамическое меню

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать в Scene Builder'e или в Controller'e, динамическое меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на иконку меню левой панели сворачивалась и оставались видны только иконки, а правая часть окна растягивалась.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать ScaleTransaction для уменьшения панели меню, текст пропадет когда ему не останется места.